# When trying to search in Windows 7 Start Menu, no related program is found

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate. Whenever I click on the "Start" button and then in the search box type anything such as "calc", "notepad", "mstsc", etc., no related program found and nothing is launched when press "Enter".
It always shows

- Programs
- Control Panel
- Documents
- Microsoft Office Outlook
- Files

[image]

Comment: Do you get the desired results from see more results?

Answer (score 0):

You could try rebuilding the Windows Search index.

```
1. Open Control Panel
2. Click Indexing Options
3. Click Advanced (accept UAC if prompted)
4. Click 'Rebuild'
```

Note this will take a while to process, and will cause slow hard drive response in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I got a fix from the Microsoft support article [The "Search programs and files" box does not display search results correctly in Windows 7 and in Windows 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977380/en-us).
Microsoft has confirmed that this is a problem in the Microsoft products.

> **WORKAROUND**
>
> Important This section, method, or task contains steps that tell you
>   how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if
>   you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you
>   follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the
>   registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a
>   problem occurs. For more information about how to back up and restore
>   the registry, click the following article number to view the article
>   in the Microsoft Knowledge Base: [322756](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756) How to back up and restore the registry in Windows
>   To work around this issue, use the following
>   method:
>
> **Delete the whole registry subkey**
>
> - Press the Windows logo key + R on your keyboard.
> - In the **Run** box, type **regedit** and then press **ENTER**.
> - Locate the following registry subkey: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{ef87b4cb-f2ce-4785-8658-4ca6c63e38c6}`
> - Right-click this subkey, and then select **Delete**.
> - Restart the computer.

This workaround did work for me.